# Plone3: How export changes on a permission of a portal_type

Tags: configuration, export, plone, plone-3.x

I went to the address of `zope` manage:

```
localhost:8000/manage
```

Entered my plone_site named '`foo`', than clicked on the `portal_types` link.
Went through the content type named '`MyContentType`', and there clicked on the tab `Permissions`.

Changed some permissions to assign than to some roles, and so on...

Now, I went to the `portal_setup` to try to export this changes, but didn't find an option to export that. 
I only found Role/Permissions, which is responsible for export changes on the 'main' tab `Security`, under the root of the `plone_site`.

So, how can I export my configuration on the permissions of specified content type under the `portal_type` tool?

Comment: And if you can't answer that, could tell me how I'd do that under a .py script? (using getToolByName('portal_types', )..., etc...)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, as nobody answered, I will:

On the ZMI, on the plone_types page, there's an option (a button) on the bottom of the page, to Import/Export changes.

The solution is click that button.
Although it's not possible to export the changes in a .xml format, you still can export for .zexp format (if that fixes for you).

For me it was not sufficient. So I started working with portal_workflow's permissions, because workflow permissions are preferred to other permissions.

Answer (score 1):

What you've described is changing access to the Factory Type Information (FTI) of MyContentType, which is probably not what you want.

Assuming you have a custom permission 'Add MyContentType' controlling who can add instances of that type, then you can assign that permission to the right roles at the Plone site object level. You should do that with the rolemap.xml GenericSetup file. The 'Role/Permission Map' step you've found in portal_setup will export a rolemap.xml for you.

If you want more finegrained control than that, you'll need to give MyContentType a workflow. Have a look at how your other types are setup in portal_workflow. Make your settings change with workflows.xml.

The Import/Export button in the ZMI can be useful to move pieces of content between matching (i.e. identical) Plone sites in ZEXP files, but generally I'd steer clear. The XML import/export there was broken last time I checked.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although I'm not more on that project, I'll learn more about this rolemap.xml Generic Setup you told.